# How to get the cloud service certificate with Azure REST ARM API

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-resource-manager

The service management API to get the certificate is this

```
https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<service-name>/certificates/<thumbprint-algorithm>-<thumbprint-in-hexadecimal>
```

I need the equivalent ARM API ?  Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this api call:

```
/subscriptions/%sub_Id%/resourceGroups/%rg_Name%/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/%cloudService_Name%/servicecertificates
```

Comment: Thanks! Its working ! Can you please share the link of the reference doc ? I was unable to find

Comment: there's no reference for cloud services. they are not supported officially ;)

Comment: Oh god ! :-/ Thanks for the info

Comment: Please give me the PUT/POST call for the same - to upload cloud service certificate

Comment: I need to upload a cert also, Please give me the put & post call for the same :-(

Comment: create a new question ;)

Comment: Done :-) Waiting for your answer :-/